# Elasticsearch - Conditional fields or naming alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, kibana

In my elasticsearch setup I want to search amongst a large collection of payments (billions), where each payment has multiple account names. This is due to each user being able to name assign a personal name to each account, while an account can be shared by many users. 1 account, many names (1 per user).

Simplified payment structure:

```
Payment {
    "agreementNumber": 12345,
    "accountNumber": 123456789,
    "amount": 17,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "accountName" : ...
}
```

The user needs to be able to search for and sort on account names, however the result set must differ based on user.

Eg. if Bob and Lisa both have access to the same account, but have made individual naming, sorting on account name would make the payments appear in a different sequence. The rest of the payment details however remains unchanged. This example could be repeated for several thousands users that created their own naming.

**Consideration I have made:**

- Flattened or inner object

I am unable to flatten the structure of the payment to contain all possible account names, and only use the account name for the specific user given the context. That would mean that all payments made with said account number would need to contain all names, and all payments with said number would need to be updated every time an alias is created, updated or deleted.

- Nested

Here I would create one collection of names that I refer to in my parent. This would lighten the storage as I only maintain the account names once. This comes with limitations that an update to my nested element (list of account names), would trigger a reindex of all parents (payments) as well. As one account number can be part of thousands to millions of payments this would be very expensive.

- Parent/Child relationship

Having account names as children of the parent means, that I can update the child and parent independently negating the drawback of nesting. However Elasticsearch doesn't support joins as far as I have understand, meaning I would get payments and account names as individual documents.

How do I structure my account names without it being crazy expensive?

**Note**
The limitations mentioned stems from this post:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch